# refresh/reload div tag MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to reload/refresh div tag from **Shared/_Layout** view in MVC using jquery

I have onclick function from another view to change the Session in _layout view

```
function ChangeSession(){
        $.ajax({
        url: '../Home/ChangeSession',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
    })
}
```

I want to reload a div tag in _layout to view my new session.

```
<div id="test">
'@Session["Number"]'
</div>
```

Comment: when your ajax request returns under data add 'success : function(data) { $("#sampleDiv").load(location.href + " #sampleDiv");}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Partial view and on your ajax success you can reload that partial view.Like this

```
function ChangeSession(){
    $.ajax({
    url: '../Home/ChangeSession',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    success: function (result) {
        $("#test").html(result);
    }
})
}
```